# lisp (cl-json library): add key/value pair to .json file

Tags: json, lisp, common-lisp

Using the `cl-json` library, I'm trying to add an entry, `{"main": "build/electron.js"}` to a `package.json` file.

Here's my attempt:

```
(let ((package-json-pathname (merge-pathnames *app-pathname* "package.json")))
  (let
    ((new-json (with-open-file (package-json package-json-pathname :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error)
                  (let ((decoded-package (json:decode-json package-json)))
                    (let ((main-entry (assoc :main decoded-package)))                      
                      (if (null main-entry)
                        (push (:main . "build/electron.js") decoded-package)
                        (setf (cdr main-entry) "build/electron.js"))
                      decoded-package)))))
    (with-open-file (package-json package-json-pathname :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
      (json:encode-json new-json package-json))
  )
)
```

The code fails at the `(push (:main . "build/electron.js") decoded-package)` line, complaining that `(:main . "build/electron.js")` is not a valid list. Which, fair enough, but what is the correct way to add a k/v entry into a .json file using this library?

Comment: sinve it is a literal pair, it should be quoted like `'(:main . "...")` or `(cons :main "asd")`. otherwise it is considered to be the function call.

Comment: @leetwinski: this is an answer, I think it should be one!

Comment: I agree, and I'd accept it, since it works.